# Boot process embedded Linux

Tags: linux, embedded, boot, u-boot

I am working with a system which boots from a SATADOM chip.  The vendor maintains two partitions, each for a separate version of code (mmcblk0p5 and mmcblk0p6 in this case).  On other system's I have worked with a soft link is changed after a boot next command is run.

However, there is a twist I am not familiar with (plus a couple of cul-de-sacs and dead ends); u-boot.

Which eventually lead to my question:  What is the boot process once we get past BIOS.  I am assuming the next step is GRUB (where I see the two images and their location (hd0,1 and hd0,2).  From there I am grasping.

Any tips, articles, books, insights, or suggestions (not involving self-copulation) generously accepted.

Regards,
-Dale

Comment: Not self-copulation, but you should ask on a more appropriate site. SO is for programming questions, not questions about the design of operating systems. Maybe SuperUser.com.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1066095/assuming-you-cant-directly-boot-into-a-linux-system-how-do-you-make-the-bootst/1066124#1066124

Comment: What platform / processor are you using this on?  How is this related to U-Boot?

Comment: You have to understand about bootloaders primarily, Here are the link to start with. http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/Manual